# Can I use rep on one site to set a bounty on another?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I have some questions on another SE site which I'd really like answered so I'm considering setting a bounty. However, I'm obviously not particularly knowledgeable in that other topic so my reputation on the other site is basically just the 100 bonus you get for joining a new SE site.

My question is, can I use my reputation from SO to set a bounty on another SE site, or do I have to earn bounty rep on each site? It stands to reason that I should be able to "trade" the knowledge which I can offer here for knowledge on a topic I'm less familiar with — however I haven't been able to determine if this is the case.

Comment: If you're interested, this was a feature request that was declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation is not transferable between sites.

You can only use the reputation you earned on a site for bounties on that site.

If you want to set a bounty you must earn the reputation first.

Comment: That's a shame :(