# Use local reputation for adding a bounty on a different site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounty, stack-exchange

The Use case:
[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818655/ubuntu-16-04-menus-are-always-displayed) posted on ask ubuntu. After 2 days, it has low views, no comments or answers. A typical usecase for a bounty. Only problem is, it is on a different site, so my local (SO) reputation is useless. I would have to spend half of my association bonus for adding the bounty.

The request:
Allow stack overflow reputation to be used on all stack exchange sites for the purpose of adding a bounty. This reputation would be used *only* for bounties, and not for the purpose of gaining privileges on the target sites.

Research:
This was originally proposed on MSE: [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-sit). It was declined, despite the popular support.
It was also raised on MSO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261099/can-i-enhance-a-bounty-using-reputation-from-another-stack-exchange-site) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252924/can-i-use-rep-on-one-site-to-set-a-bounty-on-another), but these were support issues asking if it is possible; instead, this question is a feature request asking for the system to change.

Possible side-effects:

- On the target sites, you can draw attention to interesting questions, and hopefully attract answers.
- On the site you are most active, your reputation becomes n-times more valuable, as it is useful on more sub-sites.
- If you participate on a smaller site, there will be more bounties available to be earned, thus more competition and more reputation.
- ...

Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting proposal I never thought about something like this, but one thing that comes into my mind is that this would create a whole other level of reputation transferring, which could go on.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this proposal should be implemented.

The whole point of having separate reputations for different communities is to gauge contributions to each specific community.  Because of this, I don't think it's fair to expect another community to which you don't contribute (since you have low reputation there) to give all your questions extra attention via a bounty.  If you want to have extra attention for you question there, get more involved.  It's quite possible that the question you think is a good question is overasked or otherwise boring for that community.  You have few ways of learning their norms without participating more regularly.

Besides, this kinda already exists as a one-time feature because of the network association bonus.  That extra 100 reputation is plenty to start a bounty for a single question.

And finally, a devil's advocate argument: allowing even more non-contributing outside bounties could stifle normal question askers on the site as they get beat out because of a flood of bounties from well-established other communities.  They would turn into a weird satellite community dependent on the other community.  Kinda like Puerto Rico.

Comment: So it would be bad for the askers, but good for the answerers on these communities. Shouldn't SE try to accommodate more the latter, rather that the former?

Comment: @user000001 No. SE deperately needs good *questions*. Because only good questions can have good answers. Lowering the quality of questions will also lower the quality of answers and make the sites less attractive for everyone.

Comment: It doesn't help the answers very much if they don't actually want to answer the question.  Because you don't know the community culture very well, your question could fail to attract answers because of the community norms.

Comment: @Polygnome: This proposal shouldn't lower the quality or the quantity  of questions asked, at least not directly. '@ryanyuyu: It could be community norms, or maybe the people who know the answer never saw it as it slipped passed the front page. Ironically, if a bounty was added, we would know the answer to that...

Comment: @user000001 You have no idea what a good question might be if you don't know that community. Being able to place bounties will therefore randomly give attention to questions that are deemed a "bad fit" by the people involved in the community, lowering their standards in the process.